# PHP force download, htaccess deny all, cant read file header

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I want to download files from folder that is protected for normal visit by .htaccess.
I found many tutorials but none is working for me.

.htaccess

```
<files "passportScan.jpg">
  deny from all
</files>
```

php

```
$file_name = 'passportScan.jpg';
$file_url = self::SERVER_URL . 'uploads/prom_conf/'.$user['uid'].'/' . $file_name;    
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
readfile($file_url);
```

When I visit url /uploads/passportScan.jpg it is forbidden. That is correct. But when I call my php method it force download the file but then there is error "Can't read file header! Uknown file format or file not found!"

**EDIT**
If I delete the htaccess it works fine.

**EDIT 2**
Link is called from email.

Comment: Show us some more code (eg. declarations of used variables).

Comment: The variables are fine. Because if I delete htaccess it work perfectly. But then the file is not protected.

Comment: `self::SERVER_URL`? Are you using full http url?

Comment: Then it's not possible to access restricted file.

Comment: yeah, I changed to relative url and it works. Thanks!

Comment: here is the [**proper** implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/257319)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the file is on the same server as your php script, just use the internal path

Comment: @tttpapi be careful, you're thinking in terms of URL, while this answer talks about a file path. The difference is that readfile does not attempt to load an HTTP url, but directly reading the file on disk, which of course works because it's unrelated to apache

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using full http url you can create file, eg. `download.php` and then download that image using `download.php?file=ID`.